# Tribal affiliation through the father

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, men-male, shevatim-12-tribes, genealogy

Which Tanakh verses support the halacha that tribal affiliation is transmitted through the paternal side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Talmud-GemaraTractate Bava Bathra 109b

> משפחת אב קרויה משפחה אמשפחת אם אינה קרויה משפחה דכתיב (במדבר א, ב) למשפחותם לבית אבותם
>   The Family of the Father are family the family of the mother are not family as it is written with regards to the Tribal census in **Numbers 1,2**(one of the 24 books of Tenach): "according to their families through their fathers house"

Answer (score 3):

In Bemidbar 26, the B'nai Gilad argue against allowing the daughters of Zelophad to marry outside the tribe of Manasseh given that the landholdings they were awarded (due to their father passing away without leaving a male heir) will become property of the tribes they marry into.

[Numbers 36](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.36?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

Comment: Doesn't that verse only support the inheritance of property within the tribe? I was looking for verses that state the tribe is transmitted biologically to the child via the father.

Comment: It's an indirect proof, @Empraim77- the landholdings would become propety of the tribes they married into precisely because their children would be members of those tribes and would inherit them upon their deaths. It's not the husbands who would inherit them, after all