# What are verses that clearly state that tribal lineage comes from the father?

Tags: tanach, pentateuch-chumash, genealogy

I am trying to find verses in Tanakh that state that the tribal lineage comes from the father.

Comment: Not the same question, but the answer answers your question- [What tribe did someone belong to if they didn't have a Jewish father?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59311/what-tribe-did-someone-belong-to-if-they-didnt-have-a-jewish-father)

Comment: *This one* actually is the same question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96414/tribal-affiliation-through-the-father?rq=1

Comment: @יהושעק, these answers are not slam dunks.

Comment: @Harel13, these answers are not slam dunks

Comment: They are the source of the halacha, @gustavoanalytics. That's what there is.

Comment: Aharon’s descendants are called “Levites” in various places, even though Aharon married someone from the tribe of Yehudah