Lineage and tribal affiliation in Jewish tradition
I am  new to Judaism, so I am reaching out to those who know a lot more about the Jewish faith. In Judaism one is considered Jewish through a mother, according to what I have been told. I wanted to know, if in Jewish tradition one's lineage and tribal affiliation are determined through the father?

Yes: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96414/tribal-affiliation-through-the-father

I didn't just ask about tribal affiliation, but also your lineage as well.

What do you mean by that?

We traditionally call people "son/daughter of [father's name]", though some on the liberal side now prefer to say "son of [father] and [mother]." If mom's Jewish but dad is not, the child is Jewish. They would then be identified as either "son of [mom]" or "son of [maternal grandfather]"

But there are aspects where mom's lineage matters too. Hint: don't ever attempt to reduce anything on Judaism.SE to a simple true/false!

It's the sneaky Christian! He keeps asking the same question under new usernames! Let's just admit Jesus is the Messiah so he can get on with his life.

@IsaacMoses IIRC you told me something about archeological evidence that once Zelophehad's daughters received stakes in the Holy Land as heiresses, some of those estates continued to be known by their names many generations later. The actual tribal affiliation of their great-grandchildren, though,

@ClintEastwood At this point, even if a Christian missionary happened to say something valid, I’d still deny it out of spite. This kind of infiltrating missionary work is too far.

I'm not a "Christian" nor a missionary, I'm asking if this view is acceptable in Judaism, I do not believe that Isaiah 53 is messianic

The child's tribal lineage is from the father. If the father is not Jewish, the child is not the member of any tribe. As an example, the blasphemer who was executed in the Bible was the son of a woman from the trib of Dan and an Egyptian man. His blasphemy occurred because he was not accepted as a member of Dan Even though he was considered Jewish.

@QwertyCTRL. things have been much worse in the past. This is more like a mosquito, than a bear

@RabbiKaii True, but that doesn’t change the fact that the amount of people like him is still way too many.

Yes, this is clear throughout Tanach that we trace family lineage through the father's line.  One place to look is in Bamidbar 4, where it states many times "למשפחותם לבית אבותם" Which means to count the Jews by their families - according to their father's household.

Do we give trolls lechem mishneh on Shabbat?
